# how to read and write a file in other folder in uwp?

Tags: c#, uwp, storagefile

I have a serious problem to work with files in UWP.
I think UWP can't access any folder. it just can use specific folders in windows like download, Image, and app directory.

I tried to work with FileIO, Stream, and StorageFile but none of this can open the file from another folder.

```
StorageFile file1 = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(@"D:\\test.txt");
```

Answer (score 1):

UWP applications act within a sandbox by default in order to protect the user's data.  Therefore, unless the user has selected a file from the file picker or chosen to [open a file with your app specifically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/handle-file-activation), you can't have your app access a specific path.

You can see all this outlined as part of the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions).

However, if you use the folder picker, you will have access to any files within that folder.

You can also request the new `broadFileSystemAccess` capability in order to access any file the user has access too, but that requires a stricter store submission process.

Comment: so there is no way to do that.

Comment: The `broadFileSystemAccess` capability should allow it, but it's probably not the paradigm to go for unless this is a very particular type of app or used in a private/controlled/managed setting.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is already answered in Stackoverflow. You can check the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57708520/how-to-solve-the-problem-of-permission-denied-while-reading-a-file-from-uwp-appl/57710113#57710113)