# Windows FolderPicker stopped working after updating to Windows 10.0.18362

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

I have code that was using the windows `FolderPicker`. After updating to Windows version 10.0.18362, my use of the `FoldePicker` has stopped working.

I have attached some code that I used in order to get the *access to file is denied* result.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.Storage.Pickers;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.Storage.AccessCache;

namespace FolderPickerTest
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        private static string path = @"filepath";
        string[] lines;

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            test();
        }

        public async void test()
        {
            var folderPicker = new FolderPicker();  
            folderPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Desktop;   
            folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*"); 

            StorageFolder folder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();  
            if (folder != null)
            {
                StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.AddOrReplace("PickedFolderToken", folder); 
            }
        }

        private void open_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            lines = new string[2];

            try
            {
                lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                errorText.Text = ($"Error: {ex.Message.ToString()}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error message that I am currently getting is:
`Access to the path 'filepath' is denied`

Comment: Where do you get the error?

Comment: Have you tried this code with a REAL file path or not?

Comment: In UWP, accessing files directly through the path is forbidden. Please use `FileOpenPicker` to select the file. You can refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57708520/how-to-solve-the-problem-of-permission-denied-while-reading-a-file-from-uwp-appl/57709180#57709180), it does what you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you are trying to read an arbitrary path using `System.IO` APIs. In one of the releases this was actually working when you declared the `broadFileSystemAccess` capability, but this is no longer the case. You now must use the `StorageFile` APIs to achieve your goal.

If you pick a folder with `FolderPicker`, you get a `StorageFolder` instance back. You can call `GetFileAsync` method on this instance to get a file by name. This is an instance of `StorageFile` which you can read using [`FileIO.ReadLinesAsync` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.fileio).

Answer (score 1):

To explain better the answer of Martin Zikmund, in Win 10 1803 (april 2018), `broadFileSystemAccess` capability was set automatically to ON in the user Settings.

Starting from Win 10 1809 (October 2018), this System setting is set to OFF by default.

You need to ask the user to explicitly set the setting ON in the Settings app, even by referencing the specific setting page directly.