# UWP: Permissions to use _stat()

Tags: winapi, uwp, msvcrt, crt

I use the [_stat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/stat-functions?view=msvc-170) function under UWP. But it repeatedly returns -1 for the absolute path to the file from my Images Library (`C:\\Users\\<<my-user>>\\Pictures\\image_sample.png`). I tried adding a permission to Images Library by adding to the manifest file the following:

```xml
  <Capabilities>
      <uap:Capability Name="picturesLibrary"/>
  </Capabilities>
```

But it didn't help in my case. Different Windows' API function work well (like I can read this file using for example `StorageFolder::GetFolderFromPathAsync`). But the `_stat` returns -1.

`_stat` works on UWP well when I use the relative path for files inside the app sandbox. Is it possible to use it for an external directory (for example to pictures library)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve the problem of Permission denied while reading a file from UWP application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57708520/how-to-solve-the-problem-of-permission-denied-while-reading-a-file-from-uwp-appl)

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried with broadFileSystemAccess permission as well and `_stat` returns -1.

Comment: broadFileSystemAccess only works when using Windows.Storage API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions#capabilities-for-accessing-other-locations this API should provide everything _stat will give you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Capability [broadFileSystemAccess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions#example), and **enable the `File System` permission in the app settings**.

You can search for your app in the Start Menu, click `App settings`, and open t `File System` in App permission. Another way, open Settings, **Settings**-> **Privacy &security** -> **File System**, find your app in the list and enable file permissions. (Win+R `ms-settings:privacy-broadfilesystemaccess`)

I test UWP C++/WinRT project, follow the above steps to open file permissions, `_stat` works well, it returns 0 and can use absolute path.